# max number of clients on "mobile" hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I wanna use Ubuntu on a "normal" Laptop with a Wifi-Card and creating a mobile Hotspot (offline or online doesn't matter). How many clients can connect to this hotspot simultaneously? Does it depend on the Wifi-Card? Or is there "just" the given border of 254 assignable IP addresses?

More info needed?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: This depends on the wireless adapter and as such is off topic: Ubuntu does not limit this. Most of the common adapters reach the limit in between 10 to 20 connections though. A 2nd limit would be the speed of your internet connection. A 3rd limit would be the provider of your hotspot but as this is your system there won't be a limit, as Linux uses a setting for this. `sysctl net.core.somaxconn`  should be set at 1024.

Comment: @Rinzwind thx. I just want to offer a offline local wifi without any internet connection. I maybe should use a router to fulfill my needs....